# Declaring a strict data type for a variable in Python?

Tags: python

In python, is there a command (or a directive) that raises warning when a variable is assigned a value that differs from the previously assigned type?

```
x = int()   # "x" declared as integer
y = float() # "y" declared as float
x = 5       # "x" assigned an integer
y = 2.75    # "y" assigned a float
print(x)    # prints "5"
print(y)    # prints "2.75"
x = y       # !!! "x" is assigned a float; no warning raised !!!
print(x)    # prints 2.75
```

Comment: Python is strongly **but dynamically** typed. If you want static typing, I'd suggest you use a different language (or at least Google *"python static typing"* before asking...).

Comment: This wouldn't be theoretically possible if you wanted warnings at compile time. Does `x = int(); x = 5; x = eval(open("file.txt").read())` adhere to strict typing?

Comment: Oh, and by the way: `x = int()   # "x" declared as integer` - that is **not** what that means, it's just `x = 0`. You don't declare identifiers with types in Python, that's what dynamic typing means.

Comment: What you *can* do is use [type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and a linter, but that will happen before execution, and doesn't have much to do with python itself.

Comment: No, and this is a case where a very simple Google search would have yielded the required results.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't control assignment of global or local variables, but you can override assignment of class object attributes. Here is a class that uses **setattr** to enforce type. It has a method to assign static type (use `int` not `int()` for example) and can also assign type on first assignment of a variable. It is very strict about type but can be changed to allow inherited types.

```
class BabySitter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "_types", {})

    # if you want static assignment
    def set_type(self, name, _type):
        self._types[name] = _type

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        _type = self._types.get(name)
        if _type:
            if type(value) is not _type: # or `if not isinstance(value, _type)`
                raise ValueError(
                    "BabySitter type conflict assigning '{}': was {} is {}".format(
                    name, _type, type(value)))
        # if you want dynamic assignment
        else:
            self._types[name] = type(value)
        object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

var = BabySitter()
var.set_type("x", int)     # static "x" declared as integer
var.set_type("y", float)   # static "y" declared as float
var.z = 123     # dynamic "z" int because of first assignment
var.x = 5       # "x" assigned an integer
var.y = 2.75    # "y" assigned a float
print(var.x)        # prints "5"
print(var.y)        # prints "2.75"
var.x = var.y           # <== exception is raised
print(var.x)        # prints 2.75
```

Comment: Made me smile. Now, I feel I'm getting somewhere. I'll test it.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that's from the original example and isn't very clear here. I'll change it.

Comment: You should add it to the examples [here](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69538/are-outdated-comments-an-urban-myth)! :P

Answer (score 7):

Python versions 3.6 and higher support type checking. Check out this article:
[How to Use Static Type Checking in Python 3.6](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/learn-how-to-use-static-type-checking-in-python-3-6-in-10-minutes-12c86d72677b)
It was written by Adam GeitGey - back in 2017. No need to use a different language!

Comment: Another article published in 2019: https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/